# HTML Form sending wrong file payload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, request

Got the following form for an file upload:

```
<form id="uploadCSVForm" action="../admin/account?CSRFToken=$CSRFToken"
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="opacity: 0;">

   <input id="uploadCSV" type="file" accept=".csv"  
          onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();"/>
</form>
```

The file upload dialog is triggered with jQuery:

```
function importCSV() {
   $('#uploadCSV').click();
}
```

The function `importCSV()` is executed when a specific button is clicked.

What I want is, that when the `Open` button from the file upload dialog is clicked, the chosen file should be send to the server.

With the code mentioned above the form is sending the following request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryB4a9e2nyaO3MNCw2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CSRFToken"

F5VhCnbCTVWhapxZhQJZ
------WebKitFormBoundaryB4a9e2nyaO3MNCw2--
```

The request hasn't the payload from the chosen file, instead it has the `CSRFToken` as payload, which is the value from the action parameter of the form. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a `input file type` is clicked it popups a window to select a file so you should trigger `submit()` instead of file `click()` function like,

```
function importCSV() {
   $('#uploadCSVForm').submit(); // here form should be submitted.
}
```

Comment: If I do so, no file upload dialog is triggered. There is just the same request with the wrong payload send to the server.